# laravel: query get duplicate records laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, record, query-builder

when i write this query. i have a two records in shown in result
although the table has only one.

```
$side_messages = Message::orderBy('id' , 'desc')
->where('to_id' , Auth::id())->orWhere('from_id' , Auth::id())->first();
dd($side_messages);
```

The result:

```
object(Message)#412 (20) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "to_id" [1]=> string(7) "from_id" [2]=> string(3) "msg" [3]=> string(4) "seen" } ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["from_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["to_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["msg"]=> string(18) "test_query" ["seen"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } ["original":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["from_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["to_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["msg"]=> string(18) "test_query" ["seen"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) }
```

Comment: That looks like one object to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one value not two but it's repeated for some reason one for `#attributes:[]` and the other for `#original:[]`

Answer (score 0):

**first** method return a single model instance (**Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection**).

If you need to debug how much row is returned, you can use

```
$count = Message::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->where('to_id' , Auth::id())->orWhere('from_id' , Auth::id())->count();
```

I think the result your posted is an instance of your Message model. So you can't be sure that it's returning duplicate record.

**first** method always return single instance of model. Not collection (multiple record) of model instance.

Comment: the count returns (1) indeed .. but i was wondering why the result came in that way. but thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

This dump You post is a model object, so it contains all the model settings. The thing that is important is the section

object(Message)#412 (20) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "to_id" [1]=> string(7) "from_id" [2]=> string(3) "msg" [3]=> string(4) "seen" } ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) `["attributes":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["from_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["to_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["msg"]=> string(18) "test_query" ["seen"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } ["original":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["from_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["to_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["msg"]=> string(18) "test_query" ["seen"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" }` ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) }

For much cleaner dump execute this:

```
 $side_messages = Message::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->where('to_id' , Auth::id())->orWhere('from_id' , Auth::id())->first();
        dd($side_messages->toArray());
```

And show me where is second object?!